# Styling Links in MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering how I can style my plain links:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.id })
```

To look like my submit button styles like this:

[image]

Current submit button CSS:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #438ECE;
border: 1px solid #004989;
color: #FFFFFF;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eas8v/

Comment: I made it an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eas8v/

```
a
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #438ECE;
    border: 1px solid #004989;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial; Helvetica, Sans-seif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```